# Java 8 String Join weird behavior

Tags: java

Using `String.join`  i am getting unexpected output. Code below should print `ABC` but instead prints `BAC`

```
System.out.println(String.join("A", "B", "C"))
```

Comment: This might be a case of when looking up the documentation (or even looking at the tooltips in the IDE) would have been quicker than writing a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter for `join` is **delimeter**, that's why you see `BAC` instead of `ABC`. If you try `System.out.println(String.join("", "A", "B", "C"))` you will get `ABC`

Answer (score 7):

In the [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method, the first parameter is the delimiter, and the rest of the arguments are the strings to join using the delimiter. So your code is basically saying "join `B` and `C` using the `A` delimiter".

Perhaps you are going for something like this:

```
System.out.println(String.join("", "A", "B", "C")) // ABC
```